# Uploading files to directory in Jhipster

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to build the back and front end parts of **files uploader** in an app built with jhipster 4.0.0, with angularjs. 
How can I proceed ? Jhipster is actually giving acess for creating blob type columns with the entities builder , but isn't it a bad idea to store image in the database?

So, how can I build that file uploader ?

Comment: What about giving details? like Jhipster version, angular 1 or 2. Storing images in blobs is neither bad nor good, it depends on your use case. It works with postgresql.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of jhipster which is 4.0.0, with angularjs. 
1- So isn't it a bad idea to store large images in blobs in the database ?
2- using the entity builder, both front and back parts are implementing code for the blob but nothing is created in the databse. there isn't a column taking the blob. and I have a 500 (Internal Server Error) when I try to upload something + terminal is showing "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "profile_image" of relation "member" does not exist
  Position: 60"

Comment: Rather than using comments, edit your question and format it correctly otherwise it's difficult to understand.

Comment: By the way, I just tested it and it works fine with both h2 and postgresql. If column profile_image does not exists ,maybe it's because you did not restart the java server after adding the entity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GaëlMarziou
I created a new app with jhipster a and this time, the blob injection in the database is working. I guess the error came from my other app's configuration. 
But, talking about storing images in the blob, I found this article https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/ 
that's why I try to avoid using them and I'm looking for another alternative using file uploading in a local repertory; and that was my main question if it was not clear.

Comment: Well, it's a paper from 2006. Some SQL databases store large objects differently from other column types to optimize. Anyway, starting from JHipster server code and modifying it to save your field to a file is easy and you'll find many examples on how to do it in Spring MVC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option you can consider if you don't want to save the file/image as a blob to the database is to create a separate file upload/retrieval service (ours was using MongoDB gridFs as we were dealing with large files) and only send the file id (or file path) of the successfully uploaded file when you save/update the entity.

You can use ng-file-upload to help manage this, note that below code is using angularJS version 1.

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="save(userUploadedFile)" show-validation>
    <div class="form-group">
                <div ng-show="entity.image == null">
                    <label class="control-label" for="field_file">Image</label>
                    <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="userUploadedFile" name="file" id="field_file" 
                        ngf-max-size="8MB" ng-disabled="disableFile" ngf-change="upload($files)"  ngf-accept="'image/*'"/>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="removeUserUploadedFile()" ng-show="userUploadedFile">Remove</button>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="editForm.file.$invalid">
                    <p class="help-block" ng-show="editForm.file.$error.maxSize">Error! Image exceeds 8MB file limit</p>
                </div>
                <my-server-file file-id="entity.image" on-delete="onRemoveServerFile()"/>

        </div>
        <!-- include submit button etc -->

</form>
```

The my-server-file directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myServerFile', function(UrlService, FileService, $log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                fileId: "=fileId",
                callbackOnDelete: "&onDelete"
                    },
            template :  "<div ng-if='fileId'>" +
                "<a ng-if='fileId' ng-href='{{serverFilePath}}' target='_blank' download='{{fileName}}'>{{fileName}}</a>" +
                "<button type='button' ng-click='deleteServerFile()' ng-show='fileId'>Remove</button>" +
                "</div>",
            controller: ['$scope', 
                         function($scope) {

                            $scope.getFile = function(fileId) {
                                if(fileId){
                                    $scope.serverFilePath = UrlService.getContextPath() + '/api/file/' + fileId;
                                    FileService.getFileMetaData(fileId).then(function(file){
                                        $scope.fileName = file.name;
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            $scope.deleteServerFile = function(){
                                FileService.deleteFile($scope.fileId).then(function() {
                                    $scope.callbackOnDelete();
                                });
                            }
                         }
                     ],
                     link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {
                         scope.$watch('fileId', function(value) {
                             scope.getFile(value);
                         })
                     }
        }
    })
```

Your controller will need to upload the file before it saves.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').controller('myAppController',
    ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'entity', 'UrlService', 'Upload', '$timeout', 'MyEntity'
        function($scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, entity, UrlService, Upload, $timeout, MyEntity) {

        $scope.entity = entity;
        $scope.load = function(id) {
            MyEntity.get({id : id}, function(result) {
                $scope.entity = result;
            });
        };

        $scope.onRemoveServerFile = function() {
            //Need to remove the file reference from the entity.
            $scope.entity.image = null;
            if($scope.entity.id){
                MyEntity.update($scope.entity);
            }
        }

        $scope.removeUserUploadedFile = function() {
            $scope.userUploadedFile = null;
        }

        var uploadFile = function(file){
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: UrlService.getContextPath() + '/api/file',            
                file: file
              });

              file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                  file.result = response.data;
                  $scope.entity.image = file.result.fileId;
                  saveEntity();
                });
              }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                  $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
              }, function (evt) {
                // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
              });
        }

        var onSaveSuccess = function (result) {
            $scope.isSaving = false;
            $scope.$emit('myApp:entityUpdate', result);
            $uibModalInstance.close(result);
        };

        var onSaveError = function (result) {
            $scope.isSaving = false;
        };

        var saveEntity = function() {
            $scope.isSaving = true;
            if ($scope.entity.id != null) {
                MyEntity.update($scope.entity, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
            } else {
                MyEntity.save($scope.entity, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
            }
        };

        $scope.save = function (file) {
            if(file != null){
                uploadFile(file);
            }
            else {
                saveEntity();
            }
        };
}]);
```

This does introduce some drawbacks though, when you delete the entity you will need to delete the file separately.

Create a simple FileSerivce to interact with the backend.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('FileService', function ($http) {
        return {
            getFile: function(fileId) {
                return $http.get('api/file/' + fileId).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            getFileMetaData: function(fileId) {
                return $http.get('api/file/' + fileId + '/metaData').then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            deleteFile: function(fileId) {
                return $http.delete('api/file/' + fileId);
            }
        }
    });
```

And finally your REST controller, here we are delegating to a custom wrapper for GridFs but you could just save it to the file system and return the full path as the id.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/file")
public class FileController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileController.class);

    @Inject
    private GridFsService gridFsService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, String> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {
        GridFSFile storeFile = null;
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            storeFile = gridFsService.storeFile(file);
        }
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("fileId", storeFile.getId().toString());
        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{fileId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(
            @PathVariable String fileId) throws IOException {

        return gridFsService.getFile(fileId).map(f -> new ResponseEntity<> (
                new InputStreamResource(f.getInputStream()),
                HeaderUtil.createFileContentLengthAndContentTypeHeaders(f.getLength(), f.getContentType()),
                HttpStatus.OK
                )).orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));


    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{fileId}/metaData", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> getFileMetaData(
            @PathVariable String fileId) throws IOException {

        Optional<GridFSDBFile> optFile = gridFsService.getFile(fileId);
        if(!optFile.isPresent()){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        GridFSDBFile file = optFile.get();

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", file.getFilename());
        map.put("contentType", file.getContentType());
        map.put("size", String.valueOf(FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(file.getLength())));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body(map);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{fileId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteFile(
            @PathVariable String fileId) throws IOException {
        log.debug("REST request to delete File : {}", fileId);
        gridFsService.deleteFile(fileId);
    }

}
```